# HTML display different content on projector screen

Tags: html, web, projector

I want to display certain HTML on the projector and have something else on the main screen, like in PowerPoint when you use a projector, for example. Is this possible with HTML, or anything else in the web?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use JavaScript, or CSS media queries to get the result you're after.